# MongoDB simple TimeSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, time-series

I'm trying to build a simple time series API that would do the following:

1. Everyday at 00h a CRON job goes to a facebook API and GET's multiple facebook pages fan counts, then saves them in mongoDB like this:

`{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c13b3663b720419c7806a4f"), 
    "name" : "PageName", 
    "dateUpdated" : "2018-12-17T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "likes" : [
        {
            "date" : "2018-12-14T00:00:00.000Z", 
            "value" : NumberInt(74154)
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2018-12-15T00:00:00.000Z", 
            "value" : NumberInt(89154)
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2018-12-17T00:00:00.000Z", 
            "value" : NumberInt(86745)
        }
    ]
}`

Everyday when CRON does its job, the "Likes" array gets updated with the like count of that day.

2. I query the API by passing a page name and date range for probably two days, and the API then returns me the difference in value and in percent between the two objects in "likes" array by the date range.

so I'd love to do a api call like this:

`https://api.com/likes?name=PageName&from=2018-12-14&to=2018-12-17`

and get a json resposne like:

`{ before: 74154, now: 86745, change: 12.591, changePercent: +10% }`

Is it possible to do this with mongo? I suppose aggregation is what I need?
I'm fairly new with the database and the back-end javascript programming (I'm a frontender), so any help would be appreaciated.

BTW, is my schema design even correct? Should I create a mongoose scheme for the Page, then another scheme for the likes entry, and then ref the likes entry scheme in the page scheme?

If I'm being cofusing please just ask me for any info You need, I'll try to respond quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation would be using an aggregation:

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$likes'
    }
  }, {
    $match: {
      'likes.date': {
        $gte: new Date('2018-12-14'), 
        $lte: new Date('2018-12-17')
      }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: null, 
      first: {
        $first: '$$ROOT'
      }, 
      last: {
        $last: '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  }, {
    $addFields: {
      before: '$first.likes.value', 
      now: '$last.likes.value'
    }
  }, {
    $addFields: {
      change: {
        $subtract: [
          '$now', '$before'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    $addFields: {
      changePercent: {
        $multiply: [
          {
            $divide: [
              '$change', '$before'
            ]
          }, 100
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
      before: 1, 
      now: 1, 
      change: 1, 
      changePercent: 1
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow, thank You @Gabriel Ferrarini , exactly what I was looking for! :)